# Building a dev version of a react application, continuously, for development

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I just created a react application by running:

```
create-react-app foo
```

which created a `package.json` file with:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

`npm start` and `npm run build` both run as intended, but this application is the frontend to a Django application, so, to have dev mimic production a bit better I don't want to serve the app with `node.js`. What I want to do is continuously build the assets, html, js, etc and let Django serve them like any other HTML/JS/CSS. I remember Webpack doing this last time I played with it a couple of years ago.

How do I do it in the context of this react application? In short, how do I make `npm run build` run continuously on file changes and generate dev assets.

Comment: This seems relevant https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4135

Comment: if I understood what you want to achieve correctly, you could use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) it has the functionality to watch file changes

Comment: @UlugToprak watching for file changes is only part of the problem. Building the app in dev mode is the other part. I'd be skeptical of a system that separates these two things being performant enough though.

Comment: As per the issue I linked, you need to use some kind of workaround, typically by using a different environment variable to determine the environment in which you're working

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `watch` package as a dev-dependency and add a script in your `package.json` that watch for changes in src folder and run `npm run build`:

```
npm install --save-dev watch

// package.json
"scripts": {
  "watch": "watch 'npm run build' src/"
}
```

Then, while you work, keep open a tab with:

```
npm run watch
```

Consider, though, that the build could be a long process. It depends on the size of your application.

Comment: `npm run build` builds a production bundle, I need the development bundle for development. Also, starting `npm run build` every time there's a change is too slow. `npm run build` takes more than 30 seconds to run in my computer. `npm start` reload the changes almost instantly.

Comment: `npm start` is almost instant because it uses hot-reloading aka it proxy methods to know the smallest part of code to change in the browser.